# pandas dataframe how can I number each group of rows between each occurrence of a start and an end point sequentially?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

# create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'event': ['start', '', '', 'end', 'start', '', 'end', 'start', 'end']
})
```

With this dataframe, I'm looking for this result:
[image]

How can I do this?

I've tried groupbys and other solutions, but I can't seem to find it. Any help would be appreciated!

Alternatively, how can one get this result?
[image]

Comment: Can you have rows in between end and the next start? Or a start without end? How should it be handled?

Answer (score 2):

Use `cumsum` with equals condition creating a boolean series:

```
df['count'] = (df['event'] == 'start').cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   value  event  count
0      1  start      1
1      2             1
2      3             1
3      4    end      1
4      5  start      2
5      6             2
6      7    end      2
7      8  start      3
8      9    end      3
```

Or,

```
df['count'] = (df['event'] == 'start').cumsum()
df['number'] = df.groupby((df['event'] == 'start').cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
   value  event  count  number
0      1  start      1       1
1      2             1       2
2      3             1       3
3      4    end      1       4
4      5  start      2       1
5      6             2       2
6      7    end      2       3
7      8  start      3       1
8      9    end      3       2
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! What if I wanted to do the opposite and have another column, let's say it's called 'number' and have the result look like this:

value | event | count | number

1           start        1             1
2                          2.            1
3           end         3.            1
4           start         1             2

and so on?

Comment: `df['Number'] = df.groupby((df['event'] == 'start').cumsum()).cumcount() + 1`